# How to query data between december to january

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a query as shown below :

```
Select date
From Table_A a
Where (a.FIDG_FCLT_STATUS In ('CLSNM','CLSTR','CLSWP','FULTR','OPRTN','PARTR','TINPR'))
And PARAMETER_TYPE = 'FIC'
and (MONTH(END_DATE)>='11' or MONTH(END_DATE)>='12' or MONTH(END_DATE)='1') AND (YEAR(END_DATE)>='2022')
order by end_date
```

Goals :
I have to query data between November 2022 - January 2023 or December 2022 - February 2023 (assumption the range is 3 months). I use the query given on top and the result is January 2023, November 2023, and December 2023

I am using Microsoft SQL server

Comment: Are you going for Fiscal Year  ?

Comment: the "Select date" is just an example, the concern is on the MONTH(END_DATE) which is the parameter.

I tried using >= startdate and <enddate and it's not working due to months and year splitted up. As u can see the "11","12","1" are referring to months (November 2022, December 2022, and January 2023).

Comment: @JohnCappelletti if I'm not getting your point wrong, yes. The query might be used in next year too (example November 2023, December 2023 and January 2024)

Comment: I don't understand. Why doesn't it work to just do `and END_DATE >= '20221101'  AND END_DATE < '20230201'`

Comment: `MONTH(END_DATE)>='11' or MONTH(END_DATE)>='12' or MONTH(END_DATE)='1'` Honestly, why so complicated (even if it is not completely accurate)? You can use `MONTH(END_DATE) in (1, 11, 12)` Won't solve your problem - but writing better code should be a goal as well.

Comment: In what calendar is it needed to check for >= 11 and then also >= 12 for the month? There are no values where the second predicate would ever be needed? But this whole thing is kind of a mess. Using a date range is not only easier to read and understand, it is also sargable which all those functions are not.